# Using a subquery in HAVING statement

Tags: soql

I need to use a subquery in a the HAVING statement so that we neglect the parent account if it does not have any child account. As follows the SOQL query that I have right now:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM Accounts__r)
FROM Account
WHERE Type = 'Business Partner'
HAVING (SELECT Id FROM Accounts__r) > 0
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if its master detail relationship means why cant you create roll up summary and you can check that condition,

Comment: Hi @AnnappaPH thank you for your comment, unfortunately, it is not possible to create a roll up summary field from parent account and child accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have Salesforce limitation that we can't use same object twice in SOQL

`The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type`

You can achieve this by using two SOQL

```
List<Account> lstChilds = [Select Parent_Account__c From Account Where Parent_Account__c  != ''];
Set<Id> setParentAcIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Account acc : lstChildIds){
     setParentAcIds.Add(acc.Parent_Account__c );
}
List<Account> lstAccHavingChild = [Select Id, Name From Account Where Id in : setParentAcIds];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [developer documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having_considerations.htm) can't use semi-joins or relationship queries with a `HAVING` clause:

> A HAVING clause can't contain any semi- or anti-joins. A semi-join is a subquery on another object in an IN clause to restrict the records returned. An anti-join is a subquery on another object in a NOT IN clause to restrict the records returned.

You'll have to store the count directly on each record and filter using a `WHERE` clause. If you have a master-detail relationship you should be able to create a roll-up summary and filter on that. If it's just a regular lookup you could use a flow or trigger (or the excellent [declarative rollups tool](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)) to store the count directly on the contact.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of application, you should use `WHERE IN`.  However, per [Sunil](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/59459/sunil-aware), whereas we can do this:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts)
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
LIMIT 10
```

We cannot do it with self-referencing keys, for instance:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM ChildAccounts)
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM Account)
LIMIT 10
```

Returns the error:

```
The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type
```